# Particular solution of a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a general (maybe naive) question.
Let's suppose I have the following diff. eq.$$y''(x)+a~y'(x)=b(x)$$ To solve it, I cand do a change of variable and write: $$u'(x)+a~u(x)=b(x)$$ Then, if I find the particular solution to be $$u_p(x)=f(X)$$ Can I find the particular solution of the original equation just by doing: $y_p(x)=\int u_p(x) dx$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: You have $u=y'$ and you need $y$. Therefore...

Comment: Yeah...Just to be sure. $$$$Thank you :)